# Unable to do maven clean install

Tags: android, maven, build-process, pom.xml

I am new to this maven concept, I am building one android application for which I am want to robospice lib. Rebospice demo example need maven clean install. I installed maven on my ubuntu 12.04

```
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_10, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-35-generic-pae", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Then I tried maven clean install on my demo project it gives following error

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:jar:1.3.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.351s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 21 15:15:55 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/124M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project robospice-sample-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-sample-core:apk:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:jar:1.3.2-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException.
```

Whats the problem behind this.. Need help to solve this problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to configure your maven repositories (You tell maven where to get the dependencies)

OR

Something went wrong the first time you tried to download the artefact.

If this is the later, you can solve the problem by browsing your ".m2" folder and go and see if the corresponding folder contains just metadata files or if it contains the jar and the pom as well. I something looks wrong, you can just delete the folder and retry to build your project.

By the way, it seems that this project "robospice" has a more recent version available (and stable, not snapshot), so you might want to try to use 1.3.1 instead of 1.0.0 SHAPSHOT, if it fits with your project needs.

Comment: Hye Samuels Thank you for quick reply. I remove repository folder from  .m2 and build my project it creates new repository folder but again giving same error. my sample project containing POM.xml but still giving error... Need help... thank you...

Comment: It seems that there is an issue in the packaging of the version you uses. Maybe the robospice:jar:1.3.2-SNAPSHOT was not deployed on a public maven repository. Can you try to switch to 1.3.1 version, and see if you can build ?

Comment: I think Samuel is correct here. Looking at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.octo.android.robospice/robospice, only 1.3.1 is released.

Comment: Hi samuel and duncan thank you for your help... I build it successfully.. I also change some fields in pom file like I give my sdk path and change target version of android. Thank you for your help...